# List all Unavailable layers in QGIS (3.x) project with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, layers

I am looking for a Python macro to list layers which are unavailable in a QGIS project with a large number of layers.

The following code lists all layers in the current project:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
print(layers)
```

I would like to also show the status (available, unavailable) for each of the layers. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Add the code you tried with or your question will likely be closed

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You're right!! Well I try to play with macro like this one                        
 from qgis.core import QgsProject
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print(names)  but I'm unable to extract the quality of data (available or not)

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify code. There are much better formatting options, and folks are expected the code to be in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Add some code to better explain the question.

Comment: You can use the `isValid()` function to query whether the layer is available. In your example, you could print the names and validity of all layers like this: `for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items(): print(layer[1].name(), layer[1].isValid())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isValid()` function to query whether the layer is available. This is the function that is also used to decide whether the ["unavailable layer" icon](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/299a28b42d8744da88d14753a2a5129d0b9ec0f4/src/app/qgslayertreeviewbadlayerindicator.cpp#L109) is shown in the layer tree in QGIS.

In your example, you could print the names and validity of all layers like this:

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items():
    print(layer[1].name(), 'Available' if layer[1].isValid() else 'Unavailable')
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you I solved it!!

Comment: @FrancescoZucca: That's great! If you found a different approach for solving this feel free to also add an answer. If this answer solved the problem, you can upvote and accept the answer by clicking the triangle and the check mark.