# Summarize unavailable layers

Tags: qgis, layers

I have created a template for my work team, which references layers from a wide range of sources. (WMS, WFS and PostGIS, among them)

I have used the Atlas to iterate themes, resulting in a 1 page layout that outputs a collection of maps each showing a different theme for a given single site.

The problem I have is; if there are any issues loading a dataset, some of the users have not noticed and have been generating figures that indicate that there are no features in the vicinity of the site, however in reality there has just been a problem loading the source.

In an ideal world, I would be able to create a table of loaded layers, along with a check box to confirm a good connection, or have a check box on the legend

The idea I have is to create a layout with a tiny (1cm square) map for each theme item, locked to a position where we KNOW there to be a feature. The square would be populated with each feature if present and empty if there is a fault. I suppose i could take this one step further and in the table that controls my themes, include X,Ys for that known position so that the "check" map is relocated for each theme as it iterates through them.

Am I missing anything? I find it odd that there isn't a method of including this sense check in outputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of work using QGIS expressions and custom functions.

I first thought you could just use `layer_property(layer,...)` with a suitable property to check whether the layer is available. But in testing it now, none of the available properties seems to work for both vector and raster, be reliably not cached (i.e. return NULL or similar if layer is unavailable versus last saved version in the project file when it was available), and not be computationally expensive if it is available (e.g. counting features).

However, you can define a custom function and then use it in an expression. This is based on [List all Unavailable layers in QGIS (3.x) project with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358906/list-all-unavailable-layers-in-qgis-3-x-project-with-pyqgis):

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def layer_valid(layerid, feature, parent):
    """
    <i>Usage:</i> <b>layer_valid(layer)</b>
    <br>Tests whether given layer is valid, i.e. data source available. The layer is specified by its ID
    <br>Based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358906/list-all-unavailable-layers-in-qgis-3-x-project-with-pyqgis
    """
    # layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
    # the above commented line could be used instead to find by name rather than ID
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()[layerid]
    return layer.isValid()
```

You can then use this custom function with the layer IDs that are under the `Map layers` menu in the expression editor.

For instance, you can add a label in your map layout that prints an error message if crucial layers are not available by embedding something like the following expression:

```
with_variable( 'missing_layers',
  array_remove_all(array_foreach(@layers,
    if(layer_valid(layer_property(@element,'id')),
     '',layer_property(@element,'name'))
  ),''),
  if(array_length(@missing_layers)>0,
    'Missing ' || array_to_string(@missing_layers),
    'No missing layers'
  )
)
```

In this expression, the `with_variable` defines `@missing_layers` as a variable to be reused. Its value is an array of missing layer names, formed by iterating over all layers, retaining the names of the unavailable ones (using the above custom function) and putting in a placeholder empty string for the available ones. Then the empty strings are dropped using `array_remove_all`. Finally, the last `if` concatenates the missing layer names in a meaningful way if there are any.

You would probably want to make the label using this expression big and colourful, and might replace the text `'No missing layers'` with just an empty string.

You could of course implement the complex QGIS expression with arrays, etc. within a single PyQGIS custom function, essentially wrapping [List all Unavailable layers in QGIS (3.x) project with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358906/list-all-unavailable-layers-in-qgis-3-x-project-with-pyqgis). I chose to do it this way since I expect checking the availability of a single specific layer is useful in its own right. Or rather than looping through all layers in the project, you might manually check only those used in the layout being generated.

Comment: Thats more perfect that i had hope. Thank you so much. As you say, i can use that to put a red flag on my layouts, and an empty string when all is well. Thank you.

Comment: On further reflection, it would be a good idea to wrap the 2 actual code lines in the definition of `layer_valid` in `try: ... except: return False` block. This is to fail gracefully if you feed it an invalid ID, which would otherwise not be pretty!